# Add the time values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have an hour table in our application which stores the working hours for each associate. It has hour values as follow

```
0.30 , 
0.30 ,
1.10
```

`0.30` indicates 30 minutes  and 1.10 indicates 1 hour 10 minutes. So when I calculate the sum of hours I got 1.7, but I need to get 1.3 (I need to convert `1.10` to `0.70`).

How to achieve this?

Comment: how can you get 13 or 17 for adding 0.30, 0.30 and 1.10. Adding these up shall give 2.10.

Comment: i edited the question. adding 0.30, 0.30 and 1.10 results to 1.7

Comment: Why aren't you using time -datatype (or datetime if the amount can exceed 24 hours)?

Comment: It seems to me that the storage format is wrong. If you cannot change it as @Michael suggests, have a look at http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php which explains the required calculations. I think that does **not** do exactly what you need, but should give you an idea/direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some math calculation to achieve what you want ..

```
SELECT workHours - FLOOR(workHours) + FLOOR(workHours)*0.60
```

---

sample value:

```
SELECT 1.10 - FLOOR(1.10) + FLOOR(1.10)* 0.60
```

> result: 0.70

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to store the time in minutes  making arithmetic simple. Then in the presentation layer convert it to the desired format.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: It is an answer though? Probably the most simplistic that anyone's going to suggest.

Comment: Well, in a way ;-) but normally an answer gives a solution/suggestion to solve the OPs problem. Such general design hints don't help normally. In most cases the design of an application is not changed for such a small reason...

Comment: Got to disagree, if an application is flawed to the point of recording time in such a useless method the application needs to be fixed.

Comment: You are right - of course - but real life differs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To convert 1.1 into 0.7

(int(1.1)*60+1.1%1*10)/100=.7

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TimeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('0.30'),('0.30'),('1.10');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(TimeValue,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS vals
    FROM @tbl
)
,TheSplittedSums AS
(
    SELECT SUM(vals.value('/x[1]','int')) AS valHour
          ,SUM(vals.value('/x[2]','int')) AS valMinute
    FROM Splitted
)
SELECT valHour*60 + valMinute 
FROM TheSplittedSums
```

Delivers 130 (minutes)